# Angular 4 - trying to upgrade project - "requires a peer of" errors

Tags: angular, upgrade

I try to install the latest angular version in my project but I get tons of "requires a peer of/You must install peer dependencies yourself." errors, I have no idea how to solve this

I guess it's probably not a bug so asking on angular git hub will probably get rejected

I tried

```
npm install @angular/core@latest -S
```

also tried

```
npm install @angular/common@latest -S
```

still got the same,

why is NPM not dealing with this ?

```
npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.6.39 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir '\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN @angular/common@5.2.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@5.2.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-progress-http@0.5.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-cookie@1.2.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-cookie@1.2.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-accordion@0.0.15 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-dnd@4.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.4 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-toasty@4.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.7 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

thanks

edit : package.json ( ^ dont get updated to the latest version, I try to do it manualy)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "@ngui/tab": "^0.5.0",
    "angular-progress-http": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-cookie": "1.2.6",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "^2.0.5",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.9",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "mydaterangepicker": "^4.1.9",
    "ng2-accordion": "0.0.15",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ng2-validation": "4.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "tinymce": "^4.6.2",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.72",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "on-build-webpack": "^0.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0",
    "webpack-plugin-hash-output": "^1.3.0"
  }
```

Comment: You have a mix of angular library versions. Try to install the `4.0.0` version of `@angular/common` and `@angular/core` e.g. `npm install @angular/core@4.0.0`.

Comment: If you are trying to upgrade from `4.0.0` to `5.x` then you need to modify your package.json to allow this. Can you add your package.json to the question?

Comment: I added the packages in my question

Comment: I'll try by adding ^ on every packages

Comment: adding `^` will only update to the latest minor version e.g. `4.0.0` to `4.4.7`. You need to run `npm install @angular/core@latest` for ALL of the `@angular` packages I'm afraid.

Comment: I did : npm install @angular/core@latest @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest -S... but it keeps complaining about angular 4...wtf

Comment: ok I managed to go further installing all angular packages @ latest
@angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/router@latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of fiddling, I recreated my projects with CLI, the only descent way to fix this...

Answer (score 1):

You could 2 things:

1. Do `npm install a b c ...` where **a, b** and **c** are the peer dependecies you need to update.
2. You could install a package that take care of peer dependecies such as this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-peers

If these 2 don't work try uninstall angular/cli, delete `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files, install angular/cli's version you want and then `npm install`

Comment: I get "This package doesn't seem to have any peerDependencies"  running npm-install-peers

Comment: try the last suggest I wrote. You'll unistall angular rather than angular/cli and then reinstall it

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest Angular CLI globally on your computer. Then go to the root dir of your Angular 4 project and run the `ng update` command. It'll properly update the dependencies in your package.json to the latest Angular version.

Comment: Then install Angular CLI and generate a brand new project using `ng new hello-world`. After that, replace the dependencies and devDependencies in your project with those from the hello-world project.

Comment: yep, after days of fiddling, I recreated my projects with CLI, the only descent way to fix this...thaks